# Error in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct)

Tags: lme4, tukey

I don't understand why it is not working for the post hoc test. What did I do wrong?

> modmisto<-lme(Cobertura~Tratamento, random=~1|Parcela, data=Cover_BraquiT3)
>   summary(modmisto)
>
> tukey<-glht(modmisto, mcp(Tratamento="Tukey"))
>   Error in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) : 
>     Variable(s) ‘Tratamento’ of class ‘character’ is/are not contained as a factor in ‘model’.

Any help with this will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Tratatmento does not seem to be a factor variable, try put this before:

```
Cover_BraquiT3$Tratamento = as.factor(Cover_BraquiT3$Tratamento)
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable in my `data.frame` was of type character.
The `glht` function did not recognize it as a factor in the model generated by the `glm` function.

I Tried:

```
variable = as.factor (variable)
```

I only managed using:

```
library (tibble)
data <-as_tibble (data)%>%
mutate (variable = factor (variable))
```